# Exception been thrown in route collection in Global.asax.cs

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, exception, routes

I've been following the excellent MVC Music Store tutorial over at [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store). All was going well until I ran into this unhandled exception:

> A route named 'Default' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique. Parameter name: name

The following piece of code is highlighted when the exception is thrown:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "Default", // Route name
     "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

I hadn't modified the above piece of code at all. The only change I made to the global file was to include some code in Applicatio_Start that tells the Entity Framework about .cs class that contains sample data.

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening, and, as I'm doing a tutorial, MVC is obviously new to me. Would be much appreciated if someone could resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably calling `RegisterRoutes` twice in `Application_Start`.

Comment: I was doing exactly that - the code I implemented from the tutorial contained `RegisterRoutes` and it was already in `Application_Start`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You must have another route called "Default"

or possibly you are registering your routes twice.